# SQL to find day have max records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a tbl_transaction table in MySQL database.
with format like below:

```
tbl_transaction  (
    trans_id: int
    trans_time: timestamp
    amount: float
)
```

I want to write SQLs to

1. to find the Day which have count of records ( in table tbl_transaction) is max
2. to find the Hour which have count of records ( in table tbl_transaction) is max

Thanks

Comment: So is not a s/w to give a requirement and fetch queries please input something what you have done

Comment: Is this MySQL, or SQL Server. The implementation of a timestamp is very different in the two databases. Just code is correct, and not only that, I'm sure this question has been answered more than once on this site

Comment: yep, i want have MySQLs query, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Count By Date:

```
select 
    count(`trans_id`) as TCount,
    DATE(`trans_time`) as `Date`
from `tbl_transaction`
group by DATE(`trans_time`)
```

Count By Hour:

```
select 
    count(`trans_id`) as TCount,
    HOUR(`trans_time`) as `Hour`
from `tbl_transaction`
group by HOUR(`trans_time`)
```

Comment: Now run this queries to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for sql server..

```
SELECT datepart(dd,trans_time) AS DAY,
       datepart(hh,trans_time) AS Hours
FROM tbl_transaction
WHERE trans_id =
    (SELECT trans_id
     FROM tbl_transaction
     GROUP BY trans_id having count(trans_id)=max(count(trans_id)))
```

for Mysql

```
  SELECT Day(dd,trans_time) AS DAY,
           Hour(hh,trans_time) AS Hours
    FROM tbl_transaction
    WHERE trans_id =
        (SELECT max(trans_id)
         FROM tbl_transaction
          trans_id having count(trans_id)=max(count(trans_id)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use `group by`, `order by`, and `limit`.  For the date:

```
select date(trans_time), count(*)
from tbl_transaction
group by date(trans_time)
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

For the hour (assuming you mean hour *and* day):

```
select date(trans_time), hour(trans_time), count(*)
from tbl_transaction
group by date(trans_time), hour(trans_time)
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```